# How can reverse proxies be used to bypass company acceptable use policies?

Tags: reverse-proxy

How can reverse proxies be used to bypass company acceptable use policies? And what can be done to prevent this?

I'm doing a presentation and I just need to know how the reverse proxies can be used to bypass AUP.

Comment: As a note, StackOverflow is for general programming related questions. This question might be better off over at SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Simple reverse proxy diagram]

Based on the picture above, imagine you are a user of the client computer on the left. You connect to the site on the right, which is reverse proxying other services under its origin. Any organization that may be monitoring your traffic leaving the company network will only see the connection to the reverse proxy server, not any of the other origin servers behind it. They are effectively "hidden" from view.

Now generally, sites only reverse proxy their own internal services and components, and not other entirely different sites, but it is possible for someone to create such a setup with the aim of fooling organizational filters (e.g. using a reverse proxy to access YouTube, Facebook, and Hulu).